# Concentric circles of equal areas

Tags: circles, plane-geometry

Here is the problem:

I have an annulus with radii r<sub>i</sub> (inner radius) & R<sub>o</sub> (outer radius).  Knowing the two radii, we can compute an area of $A=\pi(R_o^2-r_i^2)$.

Now, divide A by n (A<sub>t</sub>=A/n).  Given A<sub>t</sub>, find the (n-1) intermediate radii such that you end up with n concentric circles, each with an area of A<sub>t</sub>.

This isn't that hard to do, the first intermediate radius outward from r<sub>i</sub> is $R_{i1}=\sqrt{(A_t/\pi)+r_i^2}$, and $R_{i2}=\sqrt{(A_t/\pi)+R_{i1}^2}$, etc. with each previous radius value feeding into the next until all (n-1) intermediate radii are found.

My question, is there a proportional relationship between the intermediate radii?  Say I am setting up a function in a program that needs to find the intermediate radii values, and all the user will give is r<sub>i</sub>, R<sub>o</sub>, and n.  I could write a program that finds A, A<sub>t</sub>, and R<sub>i1</sub> ... R<sub>i n-1</sub>, in order, using the previous inner radius to find the next intermediate outer radius.

But I think there is a more straightforward, proportional relationship, one where if I have what the user has given me, then the intermediate radii can be defined by R<sub>i x</sub> = f(A, n), where it's not necessary to find the pervious intermediate radius first.  Or something similar (maybe it's R<sub>i x</sub> = f(A<sub>t</sub>, n), or R<sub>i x</sub> = f(A<sub>t</sub>, r<sub>i</sub>, n), etc.).  Where the x in the subscript is whatever intermediate radius you are trying to find.

Example:

r<sub>i</sub> = 0.2; R<sub>o</sub> = 0.6; n = 5

A = 1.0053; A<sub>t</sub> = 0.20106

R<sub>i 1-4</sub> = 0.32249, 0.409878, 0.481664, 0.544059

Obviously the distance between the radii is getting smaller as the values head outward (increasing radius).  But are the radii values decreasing by a proportional value that I can compute?

I think there is, and I am led to believe this from [this comment by Professor Honeycomb on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/askmath/comments/63p1gp/comment/dfw55ur/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), where he links to [this calculator page](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3v9f733w1g), which shows a relationship ($r_2=r_1\sqrt{2}$) between the area of an inner full circle and the annulus that surrounds it.  But in my problem, I don't actually care about the area of the inner circle, it's the total area of the initial annulus I need to subdivide.

I also found the graphic in the [lower right hand corner of this page](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/Equal%20Areas/EqualAreas.html), showing how to construct annulus of equal areas, which again suggest to me some kind of negative growth factor for the value of the radii, but I just can not see my way to an answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have an annulus of inner radius $r_i$, outer radius $R_o$, which we split into $n$ equal-area annuli, and we want the outer radius $r(p)$ of annulus $p$, where $p \in \{1,...,n\}$.

We want the area between $r_i$ and $r(p)$ to be $\frac p n$ of the area between $r_i$ and $R_o$. That is:
$\pi(r(p)^2-r_i^2)=\frac p n \pi(R_o^2-r_i^2)$.
Which gives $r(p)=\sqrt{r_i^2+\frac p n (R_o^2-r_i^2)} = r_i \sqrt{1+\frac p n ((\frac {R_o}{r_i})^2 - 1)}$.

Comment: Thank you, that did it!

Comment: And I see the error in my thinking.  Instead of looking for proportionality between the radii, I should have been thinking about the values of the areas.